# Is this kanji 缶田門 related to Kanda-ku or something else?

Tags: kanji

I have a set of souvenir cups purchased in Japan during the 1990's depicting Tokyo locales. There are no markings or production information, only the kanji depicted on the cup design.

[image]

To me, it looks like 缶田門. I suppose 缶田 phonetically could be Kanda, but as far as I know only 神田 is used.

Or could it be some some antiquated usage? Or something completely different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's 雷門

> The Kaminarimon (雷門, "Thunder Gate") is the outer of two large entrance gates that ultimately leads to the Sensō-ji (the inner being the Hōzōmon) in Asakusa, Tokyo, Japan. The gate, with its lantern and statues, is popular with tourists. It stands 11.7 m tall, 11.4 m wide and covers an area of 69.3 m2.[1] The first gate was built in 941, but the current gate dates from 1960, after the previous gate was destroyed in a fire in 1865.
> https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaminarimon

[https://jisho.org/search/雷門](https://jisho.org/search/%E9%9B%B7%E9%96%80)

Comment: Thanks, I should have gotten that given the touristy theme. Is this stylized kanji used elsewhere?

Comment: I think I may have never seen this style of writing before

Comment: @user3169 If you mean the radical rain, it's a mildly cursive way of writing similar to this: https://m.facebook.com/1131791786888758/videos/1262819460452656/